# How to create a bar chart of sorted values in a panel data frame in Python

Tags: python, plot, bar-chart

I have a data frame (quarterly national account data for different countries in the OECD) that is a panel with indexes country and time. I want to create a bar chart with the rates of growth of GDP across countries for a given date with country names as xticks...

So far I have been able to create a chart with sorted values, but I am not able to create sorted country names as xticks

```py
quant = quant.sort_values('rGDP_Chg', ascending = False)

#print(quant.rGDP_Chg[:, '2019-Q1'])

ind = np.argsort(quant.rGDP_Chg[:, '2019-Q1'])

print(ind)

plt.bar(ind, quant.rGDP_Chg[:, '2019-Q1'])

plt.show()
```

Comment: For questions that pertain to data, it is helpful to _see_ the data. If this is not sensitive data, please edit your post to include the output of `quant.head()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using some dummy data:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [
    ['B', 5, '2019-Q1'],
    ['A', 2, '2019-Q1'],
    ['A', 3, '2019-Q2'],
]
columns = ['Country', 'Growth', 'Date']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)

df[df['Date'] == '2019-Q1'].sort_values(['Country']).plot(x='Country', y='Growth', kind='bar')      
plt.show()
```

**Result:**
[image]